# How do I extract data from the table using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the data from the table shown on this website 'https://www.qualitydiamonds.co.uk/one-carat-loose-diamonds/#'

I have tried the code below, but I am only able to get the data from the 4 main diamonds appearing on the webpage and none of the data from the actual table.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.qualitydiamonds.co.uk/one-carat-loose-diamonds/"


response = requests.get(url)
print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

one_a_tag = soup.findAll('span', class_='price')

print(one_a_tag)
```

Comment: The table is load by JavaScript after the browser loaded the HTML page. You have to use console to monitor network requests then simulate the request in Python. The request target is: https://www.qualitydiamonds.co.uk///umbraco/Surface/ProductSearchSurface/AjaxGetJsonData

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this code below:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = "https://www.qualitydiamonds.co.uk/one-carat-loose-diamonds/"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

price = soup.find(class_='price')
print(price.text)
```